# mysqldump - maintain character set and collations

Tags: mysql, encoding, character-encoding

I'm looking for the most secure way to preserve my database data in a .sql backup.

This:

`mysqldump -u root -p DBName > backupName.sql`

outputs also these lines for my database:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tableName`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `tableName` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col1` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `col2` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

How does this line work about the encoding?

`/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;`

I remember that those data were saved with some `utf8` encoding but not with `utf8mb4`, maybe `utf8mb4` can handle correctly all sub-set like `utf8` and `utf8_general_ci` and `utf8_unicode_ci`?

(I'm using Ubuntu with MySQL 8)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `utf8mb4` is a superset of `utf8`.

`utf8` supports only the Basic Multilingual Plane of the UTF-8 standard — i.e. 1-byte, 2-byte, and 3-byte code points.

`utf8mb4` supports everything `utf8` does, and in addition, supports the Supplemental Multilingual Plane of the UTF-8 standard.

As of MySQL 8.0.28, `utf8` is now known as `utf8mb3`. It has been [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb3.html) that a future release of MySQL will repurpose the `utf8` alias to the `utf8mb4` character set.

The `character_set_client` only describes the character set used by the client to encode character data it sends. This doesn't have to be the same as the character set used by each table, if there's a valid conversion path from the client character set into whatever is used by the respective table.

In other words, if you set the client character set to utf8mb4, and the table uses utf8 (a subset), it's fine as long as the client doesn't send 4-byte characters from the supplemental utf8 plane (this includes for example emojis).

`utf8_general_ci` and `utf8_unicode_ci` are not character sets, they are collations. This doesn't affect storage of strings at all, but it affects the sort order used as indexes are built, and it also affects character equivalence for unique constraints.

Comment: And...  `/*!50503 ... */` means that the statement is ignored before version 5.5.3.

Comment: True, but I really hope no one is using a version older than 5.5. 5.5 was end of life in 2018, and 5.6 was end of life in 2021.

Comment: @Rick James
What is the purpose of `!40101`? Why would we want MySQL versions between 4 and 5 to make useless assignments (a=b; b=a)? Shouldn't it be `!50503` everywhere?

Comment: @fires3as0n - If you are running version 4.1.1 (or 5.5.3) or newer, perform the code inside the comment.  If the version is older, then ignore it.

Comment: @Rick James I know that, the question was why versions are different?
The code executed for e.g. version 4.2.3 will just do nothing

Comment: For your version 8, all three SETs should have executed.